Issue when saving/loading custom tf.keras.Model

I am building an autoencoder implemented as a custom tf.keras.Model. While the model after training performs well, I haven't been able to save it and reload it properly. I have tried both model.save() method and save_weights() but in both case the model fails completely to perform its task.
This autoencoder is calling two others tf.keras.Model, the encoder and the decoder which in turn calls custom layers.
A residual convolution block:
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package="ae", name="ResidualConvBlock")
class ResidualConvBlock(tf.keras.Layer):
  def __init__(self, n_filters: int, activation = 'relu', is_res = False, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.is_res = is_res
    self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = n_filters, kernel_size = 3,\
            strides=1, kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding = 'same')
    self.norm1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
    self.activation1 = tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation)

    self.conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = n_filters, kernel_size = 3,\
            strides=1, kernel_initializer = 'he_normal', padding = 'same')
    self.norm2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
    self.activation2 = tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation)
    self.shortcut = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(n_filters, kernel_size=1, strides=1, padding='valid')

  def call(self, inputs, training=False):
    # First convolutional layer
    x1 = self.conv1(inputs)
    x1 = self.norm1(x1)
    x1 = self.activation1(x1)

    # Second convolutional layer
    x2 = self.conv2(x1)
    x2 = self.norm2(x2)
    out = self.activation2(x2)

    if self.is_res:
      if inputs.shape[-1] == out.shape[-1]:
        out = inputs + out
      else:
        out = self.shortcut(inputs) + out
      out = out / 1.414
    return out

An encoder block:
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package="ae", name="EncoderBlock")
class EncoderBlock(tf.keras.Layer):
  def __init__(self, n_filters=64, pool_size=(2,2), dropout=0.3, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.c = ResidualConvBlock(n_filters=n_filters)
    self.p = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size)
    self.d = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)

  def call(self, inputs):
    c = self.c(inputs)
    p = self.p(c)
    d = self.d(p)
    return d, c

The encoder model:
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package="ae", name="Encoder")
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, latent_dim:int, n_filters: int, depth: int, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.n_filters = n_filters
    self.depth = depth
    self.enc_blocks = []
    self.bottle_neck = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = latent_dim)
    for i in range(self.depth):
      if i == 0:
        self.enc_blocks.append(EncoderBlock(n_filters=self.n_filters, pool_size=(2,3)))
      else:
        self.enc_blocks.append(EncoderBlock(n_filters=2 ** i * self.n_filters))


  def call(self,inputs):
    convs = []
    x = inputs
    for block in self.enc_blocks:
      x, c = block(x)
      convs.append(c)
    out = self.bottle_neck(x)
    return out, convs

  def build_graph(self, raw_shape):
    x = tf.keras.Input(shape=raw_shape)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))

  def get_config(self):
    base_config = super().get_config()
    config = {
        "n_filters": self.n_filters,
        "depth": self.depth,
        "EncoderBlock": tf.keras.legacy.saving.serialize_keras_object(self.enc_blocks[0])
    }
    return {**base_config, **config}

  @classmethod
  def from_config(cls, config):
    EncoderBlock_config = config.pop("EncoderBlock")
    EncoderBlock = tf.keras.legacy.saving.deserialize_keras_object(EncoderBlock_config)
    return cls(EncoderBlock, **config)
    # return cls(**config)

A decoder block:
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package="ae", name="DecoderBlock")
class DecoderBlock(tf.keras.Layer):
  def __init__(self, n_filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=(2,2), dropout=0.3, is_res = False, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.is_res = is_res
    self.u = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(n_filters, kernel_size, strides = strides, padding = 'same')
    self.d = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout)
    self.c = ResidualConvBlock(n_filters=n_filters)
    self.is_res = is_res

  def call(self, inputs, conv):
    u = self.u(inputs)
    if self.is_res:
      x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u, conv])
    else:
      x = u
    x = self.d(x)
    out = self.c(x)
    return out

The decoder model:
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package="ae", name="Decoder")
class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, n_filters:int, depth:int = 4, output_channels:int =3, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.n_filters = n_filters
    self.depth = depth
    self.output_channels = output_channels
    self.decoder_blocks = []
    for i in range(depth):
      if i == depth -1:
        self.decoder_blocks.append(DecoderBlock(n_filters=2 ** (depth - i -1) * self.n_filters, strides = (2,3)))
      else:
        self.decoder_blocks.append(DecoderBlock(n_filters=2 ** (depth - i -1) * self.n_filters))

    self.final_conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(self.output_channels, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')

  def call(self, inputs, convs):
    out = inputs
    for i in range(self.depth):
      out = self.decoder_blocks[i](out, convs[-i-1])

    outputs = self.final_conv(out)
    return outputs

  def build_graph(self, raw_shape):
    x = tf.keras.Input(shape=raw_shape)
    y = []
    for i in range(self.depth-1):
      y.append(tf.keras.Input(shape=(raw_shape[0] * 2 ** (i+1), raw_shape[1] * 2 ** (i+1), int(self.n_filters * 2 ** (self.depth-i-1)))))
    y.append(tf.keras.Input(shape=(raw_shape[1] * 2 ** (self.depth), raw_shape[0] * 2 ** (self.depth-1) * 3, int(self.n_filters))))
    y.reverse()
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x, y))

  def get_config(self):
    base_config = super().get_config()
    config = {
        "n_filters": self.n_filters,
        "depth": self.depth,
        "output_channels": self.output_channels,
        "DecoderBlock": tf.keras.legacy.saving.serialize_keras_object(self.decoder_blocks[0])
    }
    return {**base_config, **config}

  @classmethod
  def from_config(cls, config):
    DecoderBlock_config = config.pop("DecoderBlock")
    DecoderBlock = tf.keras.legacy.saving.deserialize_keras_object(DecoderBlock_config) 
    return cls(**config)

And finally the auto-encoder model:
@tf.keras.utils.register_keras_serializable(package="ae", name="AutoEncoder")
class AE_model(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, n_filters: int, latent_dim: int, depth:int, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    self.depth = depth
    # encoder
    self.encoder = Encoder(n_filters=n_filters, latent_dim=latent_dim, depth=self.depth) #encoder(latent_dim, n_filters)

    # decoder
    self.decoder = Decoder(n_filters=n_filters, depth=self.depth, output_channels=3)

  def call (self, inputs):
    encoded, convs = self.encoder(inputs)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded, convs)
    return decoded

  def build_graph(self, raw_shape):
    x = tf.keras.Input(shape=raw_shape)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x], outputs=self.call(x))

  def get_config(self):
    base_config = super().get_config()
    config = {
        "latent_dim": self.latent_dim,
        "depth": self.depth,
        "n_filters": self.encoder.n_filters,
        "encoder": tf.keras.legacy.saving.serialize_keras_object(self.encoder),
        "decoder": tf.keras.legacy.saving.serialize_keras_object(self.decoder)
    }
    return {**base_config, **config}

  @classmethod
  def from_config(cls, config):
    encoder_config = config.pop("encoder")
    encoder = tf.keras.legacy.saving.deserialize_keras_object(encoder_config)
    decoder_config = config.pop("decoder")
    decoder = tf.keras.legacy.saving.deserialize_keras_object(decoder_config)
    #return cls(encoder, decoder, **config)
    return cls(**config)

To be able to save the Autoencoder and reload it without error I had to overwrite the get_config and from_config methods of the Encoder, Decoder and AE_model classes.
However I don't understand why in the case of the Encoder I had to return the config with the Encoder class deserialized, otherwise it would complain that the Encoder was unknown, while for the Decoder of AE_model, it complains that element such as n_filters are defined multiple times.
With the above configure I am able to save a model and reload it. However the reconstructed image from the autoencoder are completely grey.
Result model after training:
enter image description here
Result model after training, save and reload:
enter image description here
Question:
How can I save the model or its weights and be able to reload it for future inference or additional training?
